# Clang targeting WebAssembly(--target=wasm64) on Windows could not find C++ headers

Tags: c++, windows, clang, clang++, webassembly

I have clang 11.0.0 installed on Windows 7. I used clang++ to compile a simple helloworld.cpp and no problem:

> clang++ helloworld.cpp -c

Now my goal is to target WebAssembly, so I ran:

> clang++ helloworld.cpp **--target=wasm32** -c

This gave me error "iostream file not found". I used verbose to see that the include path had:

> ignoring nonexistent directory "**/include/wasm64-wasi/c++/v1**"
> ignoring nonexistent directory "**/include/c++/v1**"
> ignoring nonexistent directory "/include/wasm64-wasi"
> ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
> #include "..." search starts here:
> #include <...> search starts here:
> C:\LLVM\lib\clang\11.0.0\include
> End of search list.

It seems that clang is trying to look under these linux style include paths where C++ headers can be found, however I am using Windows.

As mentioned, it works without targeting wasm, meaning clang knows to look under Windows style VC++ include paths. Is there a way to look under VC++ include paths with --target=wasm64 specified? BTW I do have MinGW installed and in PATH environemnt variable.

Using **Emscripten** I was able to make it work since Emscripten had C++ headers in its own installation. However still curious if it is possible using only clang.

Answer (score 4):

To compile hello world like that you would also need a set of standard headers and libraries (aka a sysroot specified via --sysroot).  The simplest way to get those things bundles together is to download wasi-sdk (https://github.com/WebAssembly/wasi-sdk).

Also the title includes`--target=wasm64` which is not a thing that works yes, so for now you want `--target=wasm32` although if you use wasi-sdk clang this is the default anyway.

Comment: Thank you sbc100 for the quick answer. It indeed worked, although I had to use "--target=wasm32-wasi" instead of just "wasm32", and also had to copy the wasi folder to my clang(llvm) installation to stop the linker complain about finding libclang_rt.builtins-wasm32.a... Now it compiles. Although can I have a follow-up question, the output with -c option is helloworld.o, which is fine. When I remove the -c option, the output file is a.out, is this a wasm file? Is this to be expected? Thanks!