# Why do I get a 'stddef.h file not found' error when using Clang to target WebAssembly on Windows?

Tags: windows, clang, webassembly

I get the error `fatal error: 'stddef.h' file not found` when I use `clang -target wasm32 -c ./file.c`.

Clang works fine when I just do `clang -c ./file.c`. I am on windows and I believe that is the real root of my troubles. I tried installing universal CRT as suggested [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0f580a73-6f11-4aa6-abbe-6bf1438734c2/standard-files-quotstddefhquot-quotstringhquot-missing-in-visual-studio-2015-rc?forum=vclanguage) but no luck.
I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67409445/21995402) but I was not able to figure out how to get wasi-sdk to work. If that is the correct path to go down I would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well a clang, you will also need sysroot of some kind.  These are normally provided by either wasi-sdk or emscripten.  You should probably install and use of those.